# How can we skip "Checking Permission" state on mysqldump and speed up export faster

Tags: mysql, export

Problem here is exporting database is very slow specially **Checking Permissions**  where i have noticed that it's something with **FILE ** table in **INFORMATION_SCHEMA** database [image].

when i dive dive what query exactly it is performing then i got the query but i didn't get why it is checking in FILE tables with FILE_TYPE = "UNOD_LOG" [image].

basically if some one known the purpose of this one then please let me known as this is the thing which is making mysqldump slow as per mine initial check , might be i could wrong if any one known reason behind slow mysqldup and how can we make it faster then please let me known

**NOTE**:  exported database having **33 tables** with **INNODB** .

Want to make mysqldump faster to export db, as before mysql 8 upgrade it was working fast but after upgrade it's much slow

Comment: Are you logged in with ROOT username?

Comment: Using user created by devops guy to manage all application related operation @WilsonHauck

Comment: You might want to verify a ROOT login avoids checking permissions for every table before asking your devops guy if he can avoid overhead of checking permissions with the newly created user's login.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Thanks for your input actually got to known that there is breaking changes in mysql upgrade it will default manage  **LOGFILE GROUP** and **TABLESPACE** , so for efficient export use **--no-tablespaces** with mysqldump command ,

NOTE: I also found it from here:  [DBA stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/271981/access-denied-you-need-at-least-one-of-the-process-privileges-for-this-ope)

Comment: Thank You for this important information to reduce unnecessary delays.

Answer (score 0):

Please check fourth comment, you probably get proper answer.